# How do I filter observations that come below one specific observation in a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, tidyverse, tidyr

Code Language: R

I have a data.frame similar to this one:

| Type | Number |
| --- | --- |
| a | 34445 |
| b | 35485 |
| KV | 54721 |
| c | 23456 |
| d | 79498 |
| NULL | NULL |
| a | 34445 |
| b | 71458 |
| KV | 23456 |
| c | 45689 |
| d | 84792 |
| NULL | NULL |

And I want to get the observations that come after an observation with the Type variable as Key Value (KV).
I want the selection to stop when it encounters a NULL Type (does not select NULL Type value).

In summary, I want observations between the Key Value and the first NULL value after the Key Value.

The expected outcome is:

| Type | Number |
| --- | --- |
| c | 23456 |
| d | 79498 |
| c | 45689 |
| d | 84792 |

I've tried this line of code:

```
subset(df, c(tail(Type, 1:2) == 'Key Value', TRUE))
```

But it doesn't do the job.

I would very much appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: Do you know if the data type of the "NULL" value is a string or if it's something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could try iterating through your dataframe and appending just the rows you need to a new dataframe.

The following code would work assuming the "Type" values are chr data type.

```
# copy the dataframe columns and make an empty dataframe
foo <- df[0,]

# a variable to keep track of whether we need to append rows while iterating
append <- FALSE
# iterate through the dataframe
for (row in 1:nrow(df)) {
    type_val <- df[row, "Type"]
    if (type_val == "KV") {
        # if type is KV we will append the following rows until we reach NULL
        append <- TRUE
        # next since we don't need to append the KV row
        next
    } else if (type_val == "NULL") {
        # if type is NULL we will not be appending 
        append <- FALSE
    }
    if (append) {
        # append row to the new dataframe
        foo[nrow(foo) + 1, ] = df[row,]
    }
}
```